# How to take pictures while recording video?

Tags: android-camera, android-video-player, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

How to take pictures while recording video along with audio? when viewing it in gallery it has to play with recorded audio.

Comment: What do you mean by "take pictures"?  You can extract frames from the recorded video.